# How do I get the user specified list of optional command line args not containing the defaults using argparse in python?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to know which options were explicitly passed through command-line.

Consider the following argparse setup in `test.py`:

```
parser.add_argument("--foo", default=True, action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("--bar", default=False, action="store_true")
```

When I execute `./test.py --foo --bar`, I shall get `foo=True`, `bar=True` in the Namespace.
In this case, `--foo` and `--bar` were passed explicitly through command-line.

When I execute `./test.py --bar`, I shall still get `foo=True`, `bar=True` in the Namespace.

So, I need to find which args were **actually** passed while executing through command-line (in the 2nd case : `--bar`), without sacrificing the defaults functionality.

One approach is to search in `argv`, but it's not efficient and doesn't look elegant.
I want to know, if there is any argparse api or any other better approach which shall allow me to do this?

Comment: You can't. That's what defaults are for, really.

Comment: Would have to stick to searching in `argv` it seems :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers and comments here recommended to not set defaults, and then handle the defaults on my own within the code. However, the `add_argument` calls aren't completely under my control, so this wasn't really an option.

Initially I went with checking the presence of the options in `sys.argv`. This approach quickly proved inefficient, bug-prone and not at all scalable.

Finally, I ended up with this which seems to be working just fine:

```
class _Reflection(object):
    def __init__(self, source, reflection, name=None):
        self.source = source
        self.reflection = reflection
        self.name = name

    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        self.attribute = attribute
        return _Reflection(self.source.__getattribute__(attribute), self.reflection.__getattribute__(attribute), name=attribute)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        source_output = self.source(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.name == 'add_argument':
            # if the method being called is 'add_argument',
            # over-ride the 'default' argument's value to 'None' in our secondary argparser.
            kwargs['default'] = None

        reflection_output = self.reflection(*args, **kwargs)
        return _Reflection(source_output, reflection_output)

class ReflectionArgumentParser(object):
    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(*args, **kwargs)
        self._mirror = argparse.ArgumentParser(*args, **kwargs)
        return _Reflection(self.parser, self._mirror)

    def parse_args(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.parser.parse_args(*args, **kwargs)

    def filter_defaults(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._mirror.parse_args(*args, **kwargs)

mirrorParser = ReflectionArgumentParser()
parser = mirrorParser.create()

parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', default=False, action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-b', '--baz', default=0, action="store_const", const=10)
parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='*', default='bar')

print mirrorParser.parse_args([])
# Outputs: Namespace(bar='bar', baz=0, foo=False)

print mirrorParser.filter_defaults([])
# Outputs: Namespace(bar=[], baz=None, foo=None)

print mirrorParser.filter_defaults('--foo -b lorem ipsum'.split())
# Outputs: Namespace(bar=['lorem', 'ipsum'], baz=10, foo=True)
```

I have tried this implementation with argument-groups and subparsers.
This doesn't deal with `set_defaults` method, however the additions required are trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set no default. If the variable is not set, the user did not pass it. After checking that, you can handle the default yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With a 'store_true' action, the builtin default is 'False'

With

```
parser.add_argument('--foo',action='store_true')
```

no input produces

```
Namespace(foo=False)
```

while '--foo' produces

```
Namespace(foo=True)
```

with

```
parser.add_argument('--foo',action='store_true', default=True)
```

it is always `foo=True`.  That argument is useless. DO NOT set your own default when using 'store_true' or 'store_false'.

If you want to know whether the user gave you a `--foo` or not, use the first form, and check whether the namespace value is true or not.  If in later code you need `foo` to be `True` regardless of what the user gave you, set it explicitly, after you have used `argparse`.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the `ArgumentParser.get_default(dest)` method.
Basically, you iterate over all of the parsed arguments and collect which ones are not equal to the default value:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
non_default = {arg: value for (arg, value) in vars(args).iteritems() if value != parser.get_default(arg)}
```

Although this doesn't work in your specific example because `--foo` is a do-nothing argument (it sets the variable to the default value).